# reading specific column in an JSON object

Tags: json, angular, mongodb, typescript

I am fetching an object to typescript component , object contains different fields but my requirement is to read only one particular field in that object.how is it possible??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: yes, i implementing according to the document you shared. but it's not working

Comment: You have to be more specific than "not working".

Comment: can you share the code, and expected output ?

Comment: @AbduManaz plz check my answer

Comment: @raju did you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting an array of Objects. You need to pick the first element of data and call the property on it.

```
this.obj=data[0];
this.y=this.obj;
console.log(this.y.name);
```

Comment: Can you share the exact log for both cases?

Comment: for both cases the output is "undefined"

Comment: Add console.log(data) and share that. Might be your data is not proper.

Comment: for console.log(data) , the data coming properly. but entire object is coming. But my requirement  is only one field in that object

Comment: Paste that data here for debugging.

Comment: [{"_id":"5b272f50797dcc0bf8bad590","name":"aa","mobile":"bb","idproofno":"cc","car_bike":"dd","flat":"108","block":"B","customer":"suri","dov":"2018-06-18"}

Comment: One more thing, what happens when you log data[0]

Comment: the output is like this ' [ ' for console.log(data[0])

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple example you can modify your convenient,

```
public data = [{ "_id": "5b272f50797dcc0bf8bad590", "name": "aa", "mobile": "bb", "idproofno": "cc", "car_bike": "dd", "flat": "108", "block": "B", "customer": "suri", "dov": "2018-06-18" }];

  constructor(){
    for(let item of this.data){
      console.log("Data->>",item.name); 
      //here you can get any like mobile, car_bike, flat, block, customer,
    }    
  }
```

For Demo click here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccvul4